# Emitting on Windows CE

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I have these methods for getting and saving a delegate that is much faster than using reflection when it's being used a ton (thousands of times a second):

```
private FastInvokeHandler GetMethodInvoker(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod(String.Empty,
                      typeof(Object), new Type[] { typeof(Object), 
                      typeof(Object[]) },
                      methodInfo.DeclaringType.Module);
        ILGenerator il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
        ParameterInfo[] ps = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        Type[] paramTypes = new Type[ps.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ps[i].ParameterType.IsByRef)
                paramTypes[i] = ps[i].ParameterType.GetElementType();
            else
                paramTypes[i] = ps[i].ParameterType;
        }
        LocalBuilder[] locals = new LocalBuilder[paramTypes.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            locals[i] = il.DeclareLocal(paramTypes[i], true);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            EmitFastInt(il, i);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);
            EmitCastToReference(il, paramTypes[i]);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, locals[i]);
        }
        if (!methodInfo.IsStatic)
        {
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ps[i].ParameterType.IsByRef)
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, locals[i]);
            else
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, locals[i]);
        }
        if (methodInfo.IsStatic)
            il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo, null);
        else
            il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, methodInfo, null);
        if (methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(void))
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
        else
            EmitBoxIfNeeded(il, methodInfo.ReturnType);

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ps[i].ParameterType.IsByRef)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                EmitFastInt(il, i);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, locals[i]);
                if (locals[i].LocalType.IsValueType)
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, locals[i].LocalType);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
            }
        }

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        FastInvokeHandler invoder = (FastInvokeHandler)
           dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(FastInvokeHandler));
        return invoder;
    }

    private static void EmitCastToReference(ILGenerator il, System.Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsValueType)
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, type);
        else
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, type);
    }

    private static void EmitBoxIfNeeded(ILGenerator il, System.Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsValueType)
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, type);
    }

    private static void EmitFastInt(ILGenerator il, Int32 value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case -1:
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_M1);
                return;
            case 0:
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
                return;
            case 1:
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
                return;
            case 2:
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
                return;
            case 3:
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3);
                return;
            case 4:
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4);
                return;
            case 5:
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_5);
                return;
            case 6:
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_6);
                return;
            case 7:
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_7);
                return;
            case 8:
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_8);
                return;
        }

        if (value > -129 && value < 128)
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, (SByte)value);
        else
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, value);
    }

    public Object TypeConvert(Object source, Type DestType)
    {
        Object NewObject = System.Convert.ChangeType(source, DestType);
        return (NewObject);
    }
```

Is there any way to do something similar on the compact framework (3.5)?  Maybe even using native C++?